# Extract Euler Angles from 3x3 rotation matrix resulted in camera calibration process

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation

How we can extract the the three angles of orientation from the rotation matrix resulted in MATLAB extrinsic camera parameters. For example, if you given the following rotation matrix,

```
Rc_ext = [ -0.012785     0.999906    -0.004886

            0.982489     0.011654    -0.185957

           -0.185883     -0.007178   -0.982546 ]
```

Find the three angles of orientation (around x-axis,y-axis and z-axis)?

Comment: Did you even search google how to get euler angles from rotation matrix? http://staff.city.ac.uk/~sbbh653/publications/euler.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no standard definition for Euler angles. In theory you can find a set of angles for 3 rotations about any axes in any order and get the same rotation matrix. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and despair.

Many people don't bother to define which way positive rotation is, or what units they use. It once took me three weeks to reverse engineer the correct interpretation of the angles output by an ABB robot arm.

Here is my code for a right handed coordinate system where positive rotation is defined as clockwise when looking along the length of a vector. Assuming you want yaw (rotation around Z axis), pitch (rotation around Y) and Roll (Rotation around X) and create the matrix by matrix = r_z * r_y * r_x

Then here is my code:

```
function [yaw, pitch, roll] = euler_angles(rot_mat)
    pitch = asin(rot_mat(3,1)) * (180.0/pi);
    yaw   = atan2(rot_mat(2,1), rot_mat(1,1)) * (180.0/pi);
    roll  = atan2(rot_mat(3,2), rot_mat(3,3))* (180.0/pi);
end
```

Here is my code to regenerate the matrix from the Euler angles.

```
function rotation = euler_rotation(yaw_deg, pitch_deg, roll_deg)
    % rads = deg2rad([yaw_deg, pitch_deg, roll_deg]);
    rads = ([yaw_deg, pitch_deg, roll_deg]) * (pi/180.0);
    cos_y = cos(rads(1));
    sin_y = sin(rads(1));
    cos_p = cos(rads(2));
    sin_p = sin(rads(2));
    cos_r = cos(rads(3));
    sin_r = sin(rads(3));

    r_x = eye(3);
    r_x(2,2) = cos_r;
    r_x(3,3) = cos_r;
    r_x(2,3) = -sin_r;
    r_x(3,2) = sin_r;

    r_y = eye(3);
    r_y(1,1) = cos_p;
    r_y(3,3) = cos_p;
    r_y(1,3) = -sin_p;
    r_y(3,1) = sin_p;

    r_z = eye(3);
    r_z(1,1) = cos_y;
    r_z(2,2) = cos_y;
    r_z(1,2) = -sin_y;
    r_z(2,1) = sin_y;

    rotation = r_z * r_y * r_x;    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying out `E = RX(φ)*RY(ψ)*RZ(θ)` as seen in [Wiki Euler Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix).

- First I try `E*RZ(-θ) = RX(φ)*RY(ψ)` and I pick element [1,2] to get

  `0.999906 COS(θ)-0.012785 SIN(θ)=0 } θ=269.267°`
- Then pick elements [1,3] and divide by element [1,1] to get

  `-0.004886/0.99998773245525367 = TAN(ψ) } ψ=-0.279948385°`
- Finally divide element [3,2] with element [2,2] to get

  `-0.18595957899545633/0.98255769599450146 = TAN(φ) } φ = 169.28292°`